# Is it possible to control the frame of an animated mesh (Collada) with a slider in three.js

Tags: animation, three.js, collada

I want to achieve something using three.js and I wonder if it can be done.

Is there something in three.js that can allow me to control the frame of an animated Collada mesh with a slider. For example if you move up the slider it would open a door an if you pull it down it will close.

In other way, can I have control over the frame of the animation of my imported Collada object.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would appreciate similar info on controlling imported animations in three.js, but currently looking at BVH_Loader (rather than Collada).